# C++ lambda with a function call insde

Tags: c++11, lambda

The following lambda expression code is failing to compile in VC++ 2010.

```
void error_check() {}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(10);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [](){ //either add -> int, 
        error_check(); //or comment this out to compile
        return rand()%99; });
}
```

The compiler says "a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value." However, if I explicitly specify the return type or comment out `error_check();` the code compiles fine.

I read that return type part can be omitted for single return statements. Then why is it required above?

Comment: Well that's what the standard requires.

Comment: C++14 will allow cases like this to succeed, Gcc [already supports it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2714a9977d91e77644d48318e80a5da0-ba3bae90b423baa0c9600f55756b6780) as does [clang: link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2714a9977d91e77644d48318e80a5da0-d9c33a021bcc56e64905c99c3a4dc3f4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++11, a "single return statement" required for a lambda (or `constexpr` function) means that `return` expression`;` is the *only* thing in the function definition.  So you can't have the extra statement before the return statement.

C++1y will be more generous about this sort of thing, and should allow the code as posted.

Besides going ahead and adding the trailing return type, you could also work around this with a comma operator:

```
[](){
    return (error_check(), rand()%99);
}
```